# Add changing [task color] function dhtmlx Gantt in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I'm using this Gentlemens dhtmlx gantt script.

https://github.com/Ojsholly/gantt_chart

It works perfect.

So I would like to change [task] color
so I've been reading official document

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__colouring_tasks.html?_ga=2.208101525.600237831.1608522852-949493651.1608024610

And trying to add below code into dhtmlxgantt.js (This js file located public/js folder)

```
var tasks = {
  data:[
     {id:1, text:"Project #1", start_date:"01-04-2013", duration:18, color:"red"},
     {id:2, text:"Task #1", start_date:"02-04-2013", 
        duration:8, color:"blue", parent:1},
     {id:3, text:"Task #2", start_date:"11-04-2013", 
        duration:8, color:"blue", parent:1}
   ]
};
gantt.init("gantt_here");
gantt.parse(tasks);
 
gantt.getTask(1).color = "red"
```

but I couldn't find var tasks = part in dhtmlxgantt.js file.

so I don't know where to add them. Could you teach me right way please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "tasks" property in the dhtmlxgantt.js file. In the code example, it is a variable that contains tasks.
You need to use the Gantt API in a separate script. In your demo, you need to edit the following file:

```
resources/views/gantt.blade.php
```

If you add the "color" property to a task, it will work, but if you use the templates, you will have more flexibility.

Here are examples:

CSS+templates:

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/38c031774

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/b62285d9a

color property:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/3b74c0541

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/82ebe840a